# Determinant of a $2 \times 2$ block matrix whose diagonal blocks are skew-symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, block-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

> Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix} B & C \\ C' & D\end{pmatrix}$$ be an odd order matrix. If blocks $B, D$ are skew-symmetric matrices, then $\det A=0$.

---

**My attempt**

Without losing generality, we assume that order of $B: n$ is odd and order of $D:m$ is even since $A$ is an odd order matrix. And we know that $\det B=0$ by properties of skew symmetric matrix.

Then I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
M=A\pmatrix{I_n&0\\ 0&-I_m}=\pmatrix{B&C\\ C^T&D}\pmatrix{I_n&0\\ 0&-I_m}=\pmatrix{B&-C\\ C^T&-D}
$$
is a skew-symmetric matrix of odd order, we have $\det(M)=0$. Hence $\det(A)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You are really close!

Recall that the determinant of a block matrix could be expressed [this way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices). [this too](https://djalil.chafai.net/blog/2012/10/14/determinant-of-block-matrices/)

Discuss the invertibility of $D$.

if $\det(D)\neq 0$, then it's invertible and we have the following
$$
\det(A)=\det(D)\det(B-C'D^{-1}C)
$$

For the second term $C'D^{-1}C$, $D^{-1}$ is skew symmetric matrix of even order. Then
$$
(C'D^{-1}C)'=C'D^{-T}C=-C'D^{-1}C
$$
Thus the matrix $B-C'D^{-1}C$ is a skew symmetric matrix of odd order, just like $B$. Then
$$
\det(B-C'D^{-1}C)=0\\
\det(A)=0
$$

if $\det(D)= 0$, $\det(B)=0$, then $\det(A)=0$

Thus in any case $\det A=0$

Comment: why $\det D=0, \det B=0$, then $\det A=0$?